# SwiftUI MKMapView UIViewRepresentable - Simple App is crashing. Is this a 'Metal API' Library bug or did I do something obviously wrong?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, exc-bad-access, metal, uiviewrepresentable

I'm displaying a MKMapView in SwiftUI by wrapping it in the UIViewRepresentable protocol.

I think the crash may have something to do with "Metal API Validation Enabled"

I'm running Xcode Version 13.1 (13A1030d)

My iPhone is iOS 15.1

When I run the app, the map displays and if I rotate my phone the Map rotates properly.  BUT after two or three rotations the app crashes.  The top of the stack trace says:

***queue = 'com.Metal.CompletionQueueDispatch', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)***

The Error displayed is ***"Thread 12: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)"***

I've reduced the code to just a few lines shown below
 
ContentView.swift:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

MapView.swift:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = MKMapView
 
    // Required by UIViewRepresentable protocol
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        return MKMapView()
    }
    
    // Required by UIViewRepresentable protocol
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIView() called")
    }
}
```

After the Console output shown below is displayed I rotate the phone back and forth several times to get the map to rotate between portrait and landscape.  After several rotations I get the crash.
The Console Output before the crash is is shown below.

***2021-12-07 15:24:00.879362-0700 UIViewRepresentableHelloWorld[26817:1293647] Metal API Validation Enabled
updateUIView() called***

The Stack Trace is shown below:

```
* thread #18, queue = 'com.Metal.CompletionQueueDispatch', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
 
  * frame #0: 0x0000000197a3a014 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 20
 
    frame #1: 0x00000001cc5809a4 MetalTools`-[MTLDebugCommandBuffer preCompletionHandlers] + 316
 
    frame #2: 0x00000001cc536070 MetalTools`-[MTLToolsCommandBuffer invokeCompletedHandlers] + 36
 
    frame #3: 0x000000019958efa0 Metal`MTLDispatchListApply + 44
 
    frame #4: 0x000000019958f374 Metal`-[_MTLCommandBuffer didCompleteWithStartTime:endTime:error:] + 596
 
    frame #5: 0x00000001cb3fe144 IOGPU`-[IOGPUMetalCommandBuffer didCompleteWithStartTime:endTime:error:] + 216
 
    frame #6: 0x000000019958f04c Metal`-[_MTLCommandQueue commandBufferDidComplete:startTime:completionTime:error:] + 132
 
    frame #7: 0x00000001cb3fdf04 IOGPU`__IOGPUNotificationQueueSetDispatchQueue_block_invoke + 148
 
    frame #8: 0x000000010486a048 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
 
    frame #9: 0x0000000104885364 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 424
 
    frame #10: 0x0000000104870ff0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 332
 
    frame #11: 0x0000000104886188 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mach_invoke + 504
 
    frame #12: 0x0000000104870ff0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 332
 
    frame #13: 0x0000000104871e08 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 484
 
    frame #14: 0x0000000104870ff0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 332
 
    frame #15: 0x0000000104871dd4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 432
 
    frame #16: 0x000000010487d4e8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 852
 
    frame #17: 0x00000001da86de84 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 284
```

Answer (score 2):

The Fix seems to be to uncheck the 'Metal API Validation' check box in the product scheme settings.  In Xcode go to "Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme…" On the Diagnostics tab uncheck the 'Metal API Validation' checkbox.

Comment: Had to do this for Apples' own PDFView crashing after waking up the iMac, sad to see.